# OCaml Reading a char with Scanf

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to read a char with Scan f ? I don't want to read a line because I'm reading other types of variables.

4 a ... 223 5 72

Since the structure of the line is irregular i just want to worry about reading the char 'a' in this example.
Suppose I already read the int and just need to read the char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Scanf module : first open a Scanning buffer, then use bscanf with the correct scanner.

Assuming your file contains :
4 a 45

```
open Scanf;;
let b = Scanning.from_file "<your file>";;
let a = bscanf b "%d" (fun x -> x);; will return 4
let a = bscanf b "%c" (fun x -> x);; will return ' '
let a = bscanf b "%c" (fun x -> x);; will return 'a'
let a = bscanf b "%c" (fun x -> x);; will return ' '
let a = bscanf b "%d" (fun x -> x);; will return 45
```

in the doc of Scanf, bscan is recommended over fscanf.